# Identify whether it is a row major or column major matrix

Tags: c, matrix, parallel-processing

Can someone guide me in understanding whether this is a column-major or row-major matrix multiply by vector implementation? How I can make it cache-friendly for parallel computing?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int k;
    int matrix[10];
    for(k=0; k<3*3; k++){
    matrix[k] = k+1;
    printf("%d : %d\n", k, matrix[k]);
    }

int vector_in_s[]={1,1,1};

  int rows, cols;
  int vector_out[10];
  for(cols=0; cols<3; cols++){
    vector_out[cols] = 0.0;
    for(rows=0; rows<3; rows++)
      vector_out[cols] += vector_in_s[rows] * matrix[rows*3 + cols];
  }

 int i;
 for(i=0; i<3; i++){
     printf("Result: %d\n",vector_out[i]);
 }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have solved the issue, it was actually a column-major matrix multiplication. And for parallel computing improvements, we need to do row-major multiplication so that contiguous memory allocation.

Answer (score 0):

I can help with the first part;
This is a column major order, because it iterates on the columns in the outer loop, so by definition it is a column major order.
See [link](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order) for more clarification.

Comment: Yes, half of the question is correct. But if the outer loop is of rows then in code it will not change much? right?